# Do enemies have weaknesses to certain attacks?

Tags: 10000000

Does it matter if I kill a monster with a sword or magic attack?  Will one do more than another? Also what about damage from orbs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some enemies have armor against physical damage, making magic damage work better against them. Others resist magic better than physical damage.

Also, you can upgrade your weapon and your staff which increases the damage they do. So, depending on how you upgraded your weapon and staff, and what defenses are stronger on your opponent, it can make a great deal of difference whether you attack with your weapon or magic.

Orbs do magical damage.

Axes do physical damage.

Comment: Orbs do magic damage. Not sure whether it scales with your regular magic attack, possibly not but I wouldn't know where to begin to test.

Comment: Updating answer to reflect @Shadur comment.

Comment: source​​​​​​​​?

Comment: do different colored orbs do different types of magic damage?  or are all orbs equal.

Comment: Source for axes is game hint text.